# How to install Blackberry WebWork 2.0 in Blackberry Momentics

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks, webwork, momentics

I have successfully install BB WebWork 2.0 and BB Momentics. Now I am stuck with how can I create project in Momentics of BB WebWork and run it successfully. I mean how can I integrate WebWork 2.0 in Momentics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebWorks, and Momentics are two different platforms.  WebWorks of course is all Cordova based now. Momentics is for using Cascades, QML, and C++. You do not integrate WW into Momentics.

What are you hoping to accomplish in WebWorks? I'm sure I can point you in the right direction.